# How to upgrade cakephp version 1.x to 4.x?

Tags: cakephp, upgrade, cakephp-4.x

I have one project in Cakephp 1.x version. I want to upgrade into Cakephp version 4.x.
so which steps need I follow ?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the application with 4.x, there is no simple upgrade path from 1.x.